# override a CSS class if two other classes are present

Tags: css

I want to override a CSS class if two other CSS classes are present for a particular element.

Eg:

`<img class="class1 class2" />`

I want to override `class3` in this case.

I my current implementation is something like below.

```
.class1.class2 { .class3 {padding-left: 1px}  }
```

But this approach does not seem to work!

Comment: That's not a valid approach. What's the HTML for the `class3` one?

Comment: `<img class="class1 class2 class3" />` write this in html, for class3 css add `!important` for styles it will override both class1 and class2

Comment: @Srinivas Specificity is okay, don't say anything related `!important` to newbies.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am using a UI5 library, have boiled down my requirement to the above example, since we can apply some CSS properties if two classes are there in an element, I thought we could override an element as well, is it not  possible?

Comment: It is possible @DwarakeshPallagolla...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go

```
.class1.class2.class3 {
  /* these definitions are more specific and don't need !important; */
}
```

Remember this requires you to put `class3` on the element as well:

```
<element class="class1 class2 class3"></element>
```

If the only reason you wanted to add `class3` is to specify styles that should be applied when **both** classes `class1 class2` are present, you don't even need `class3`, just go

```
.class1.class2 {
  /* these definitions are more specific than those for .class1 or .class2 
  and don't need !important;
  These rules apply to any element that has both class1 and class2 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html> 

<head> 

<style>
.class1{background:green;}
.class2{background:blue;}
.class1.class2{background:red}

</style> 

</head> 

<body> 

    <p class="class1"> This is a paragraph. </p> 

    <p class="class2"> This is a paragraph. </p> 

    <p class="class1 class2"> This is a paragraph. </p> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed a selector inside another like you have done, however you can specify what should be used when both classes are present. e.g.

HTML

```
<p class="class1">A</p>
<p class="class2">B</p>
<p class="class1 class2">C</p>
```

CSS

```
.class1 {border:1px solid red}
.class2 {border:1px solid green}
.class1.class2 {border:1px solid blue}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5zjznd8t/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are showing us an image tag, I assume that class3 isn't nested inside this tag. An image-Tag shouldn't have nested elements.
With you definition class3 would be an element inside another.
For example:

```
 <p class="class1 class2"><span class="3">some text</span</p>
```

For your case it is necessary to define the class inside the same level.

```
.class1.class2 {
    &.class3 {
        padding-left: 1px
    }
}
```

The amper defines the class3 at the same level.

Since this definition is more specified than `.class1.class2` it should override those styles.